# upgrade trial to full version

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, trial

I want to publish a trial of my app. In this app, the user has to save a lot of values in the sharedPreferences. If he decides to buy the full version, would the trial be deinstalled, and the sheredPreferences would be deleted too? Does anyone know that?

It would be very nice, if the sharedPreferences wouldnt be deleted, so the full version has access to the value of the trial, therefor the user hasnt to save all the values again.

Comment: Can't you save it before the uninstall and restore after the bought version installed?

Comment: Wouldn't all thas be based on how YOU wrote the program?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the SharedPreferences are deleted when they uninstall the trial and install the full.

I see a few options you could use, either use the same app for both and use an unlock style of purchase, either via in app purchase, or by selling a separate "unlock" app.

You could save their settings to a remote server and have the full app download them from there.  This one has the advantage of allowing syncing of settings across multiple devices, downside is you'd have to make and maintain a server.

You could save them to some other permanent file on the device, but personally I hate it when an app leaves something behind when I uninstall it.

Comment: Definitely save the settings to a server, retrieve them in the full app. Only trick there is to identify the user/device - which would probably be best done via something like their google account which is synced to the device?

Comment: If you're using Google Play or another framework that offers it, in-app purchase is probably easier than setting up a server for this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, to publish the trial with a lower versioncode as the full version, so the trial only would be updated and the sharedPreferences wouldnt be deleted?

Comment: Hmm, I was wondering the same thing. I think I will give it a try as it sounds very simple solution and I can't figure out any reason why it would not work.

Comment: You cannot publish two apps having the same package name on the Google Play store.  Also, it would be better to post a question in a comment rather than listing it as an answer.